# expect script wait for anotother process

Tags: oracle11g, tcl, expect

Was trying to automate the process of installing a Oracle DB on a aix machine so I planned on using an expect script to help me with this but was having trouble. What happens is during the installation, when you run the command to start the installation the first process does some per-requisite checks I believe but then forks off to another process. In this scenario what happens is my expect script finishes running and the next process does not start.

The reason I was using a expect script was because even though I am doing a silent installation it asks the user if he had run a certain script before running the installation process.

Anyone know of how I can make the process wait and recognize the next process which is created or even just wait for a little while so the next process can start

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to not use the expect script. By using `export SKIP_ROOTPRE=TRUE` the check does not appear and can be avoided